# Reverse Iterator for List?

Tags: dart

Is there an efficient way to iterate through objects in the list in reverse order in dart?   I could use indices, but will that cause a performance hit (i.e. if `List<E>` is built internally using linked list)?

Context: I'm drawing objects from back to front, but need to process them from front to back

Ali

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until the issue [#2804](http://dartbug.com/2804) has been *fixed*, you have to iterate list in reverse order using indices. For your performance concern, it should be good because [Lasse R.H. Nielsen once said](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/c45lBlaS2DA/ufL_GDslUBQJ) :

> Lists in Dart are intended for random access

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with indices for now

Comment: Dart now has a solution. Check my answer to the question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 92):

You can now reverse the iteration of a list in Dart. Use the `reversed` getter on List.

```dart
var fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];
Iterable inReverse = fruits.reversed;
var fruitsInReverse = inReverse.toList();
print(fruitsInReverse); // [pears, oranges, apples]
```

You could shorten this to:

```
var fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'];
print(fruits.reversed.toList());
```

See the [API docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/List/reversed.html).

Comment: Did you know if this .reversed has low performance overhead? I'll use big arrays, didn't want to calc length all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if there were an efficient backwards iteration.

In the meantime, what you could do is create a list with backwards links.

e.g.

```dart
class BackwardsLinked {
    // properties, methods etc.
    // as an example, just an int
    int value;

    BackwardsLinked(this.value);

    BackwardsLinked previousItem;

    String toString() => "[$value]";
}

void main() {
    // setting up the list
    var list = new List<BackwardsLinked>();
    var anchor = new BackwardsLinked(0);
    anchor.previousItem = null;

    list.add(anchor);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(new BackwardsLinked(i * 3));
        list[i].previousItem = list[i - 1];
    }
    BackwardsLinked terminal = list[list.length - 1];

    // Iteration
    print("Forwards, as usual:");
    for (BackwardsLinked link in list) {
        // Do whatever with object
        print(link);
    }

    print("Backwards:");
    {
        BackwardsLinked link = terminal;
        print(terminal);
        while (link.previousItem != null) {
            link = link.previousItem;
            // Do whatever with object
            print(link);
        }
    }
}
```